# Как перекрасить иконку svg?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, svg

Я вставил иконку svg на сайт так `<img src="images/clock-blog.svg" class="clock"  width="25px" height="25px" alt="">` При наведении надо, чтобы у неё перекрасилась обводка в белый цвет.  Как по другому можно подключить картинку, чтобы можно было перекрасить?

Answer (score 3):

Увы, менять стили внутри тега img не возможно

Но есть всегда выход, Мы можем открыть иконку в SVG в любом любимом редакторе кода, я воспользовался Notepad++ и очистил скачанную иконку от лишнего

И добавил при наведении эффект смены заливки и обводки ...

Стили мало чем отличаются только вместо background используется fill и вместо border используется stroke

SVG не ограничивает нас в css и мы можем стили css относящиеся к SVG вынести в общий css страницы...

Смотрите пример в сниппете

```css
.icon {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

#clock {
  stroke: transparent;
}

svg:hover #clock {
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 14px;
  fill: yellow;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello SVG</h1>
<div class="icon">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <g>
   <path id="clock" d="M60.652,75.816V15.163C60.652,6.781,67.433,0,75.817,0c8.38,0,15.161,6.781,15.161,15.163v60.653
    c0,8.38-6.781,15.161-15.161,15.161C67.433,90.978,60.652,84.196,60.652,75.816z M318.424,90.978
    c8.378,0,15.163-6.781,15.163-15.161V15.163C333.587,6.781,326.802,0,318.424,0c-8.382,0-15.168,6.781-15.168,15.163v60.653
    C303.256,84.196,310.042,90.978,318.424,90.978z M485.212,363.906c0,66.996-54.312,121.307-121.303,121.307
    c-66.986,0-121.302-54.311-121.302-121.307c0-66.986,54.315-121.3,121.302-121.3C430.9,242.606,485.212,296.919,485.212,363.906z
     M454.89,363.906c0-50.161-40.81-90.976-90.98-90.976c-50.166,0-90.976,40.814-90.976,90.976c0,50.171,40.81,90.98,90.976,90.98
    C414.08,454.886,454.89,414.077,454.89,363.906z M121.305,181.955H60.652v60.651h60.653V181.955z M60.652,333.584h60.653V272.93
    H60.652V333.584z M151.629,242.606h60.654v-60.651h-60.654V242.606z M151.629,333.584h60.654V272.93h-60.654V333.584z
     M30.328,360.891V151.628h333.582v60.653h30.327V94c0-18.421-14.692-33.349-32.843-33.349h-12.647v15.166
    c0,16.701-13.596,30.325-30.322,30.325c-16.731,0-30.326-13.624-30.326-30.325V60.651H106.14v15.166
    c0,16.701-13.593,30.325-30.322,30.325c-16.733,0-30.327-13.624-30.327-30.325V60.651H32.859C14.707,60.651,0.001,75.579,0.001,94
    v266.892c0,18.36,14.706,33.346,32.858,33.346h179.424v-30.331H32.859C31.485,363.906,30.328,362.487,30.328,360.891z
     M303.256,242.606v-60.651h-60.648v60.651H303.256z M409.399,363.906h-45.49v-45.49c0-8.377-6.781-15.158-15.163-15.158
    s-15.159,6.781-15.159,15.158v60.658c0,8.378,6.777,15.163,15.159,15.163h60.653c8.382,0,15.163-6.785,15.163-15.163
    C424.562,370.692,417.781,363.906,409.399,363.906z"/>
  </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Вот у меня есть иконка svg, а как мне её превратить в  <path d="????" />   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"

Comment: где иконка , не вижу?

Comment: http://priscree.ru/img/fc412cda430634.jpg

Comment: @ПашаШаламов у меня не работает эта ссылка ...ограничение Казахстана

Comment: Напишите пожалуйста в вк. https://vk.com/id215555512